# Load enum values into dojo store

Tags: javascript, dojo, store, dijit.form

I have an ENUM like this

```js
define({
    DEFAULT:1, 
    DDL:2,
    props:{
        1:{name: 'Default', value:1, id:1},
        2:{name: 'DDL', value:2, id:2}
}
});
```

and I want to load it into a `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`

this is my code

```js
var store = new Memory({
                    idProperty: "id",
                    data: type.props
                });
var os = new ObjectStore({objectStore: store});

this.unitType = new Select({
                    name : 'name',
                    label : dojoConfig.i18n.unitType,
                    placeHolder: dojoConfig.i18n.unitType,
                    required: false,
                    store: os,
                    value: type.props[1].id,
                    searchAttr: 'name',
                    labelAttr: "name",
                    trim: true
                });
```

but when I expand the dropdown list ... it doesnt expand without any errors in the console ... any idea what I made wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dropdown doesn't show anything because the given data wasn't an Array , but a js object ,

The [dojo/store/Memory](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Memory.html) need ana array as data,

So to fix this you can edit your object by changing the object into array , or create and object from this and set to to your select , and this using [`Object.values(yourObject)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) that return an array of values from your object .

See below Working snippet :

```js
require(["dijit/registry", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/data/ObjectStore"],
  function(registry, FilteringSelect, Memory, ObjectStore) {

    var type = {
      DEFAULT: 1,
      DDL: 2,
      props:{
        1:{name: 'Default', value:1, id:1},
        2:{name: 'DDL', value:2, id:2}
      }
    };
    
    type.props = Object.values(type.props);
    
    var store = new Memory({
      idProperty: "id",
      data: type.props
    });
    var os = new ObjectStore({
      objectStore: store
    });

    new FilteringSelect({
      name: 'name',
      required: false,
      store: os,
      value: type.props[1].id,
      searchAttr: 'name',
      labelAttr: "name",
      trim: true
    }, "select");

  });
```

```html
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    parseOnLoad: true,
  };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="claro">
  <select id="select">
  </select>

</body>
```

Comment: @firstNamelastName does this helped ?